# Function with repeated setTimeout() changes on each call

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to set up intervals with setTimeout() and it works the first time the code is executed. The second time (after a new interval is created), the setTimeouts (that are pushed to intervalTimeouts) are somehow delayed. The code before the setTimeout (*rep--;* and so on) is instead executed twice, then the setTimeout is repeated twice, simultaneously. The third time the function is called, the code before the setTimeout repeats three times before the timeouts start. I tried removing the delay before the function calls itself (by changing *setTimeout(intervalRep, pause * 1000);* to *intervalRep();*) but this does not solve the problem. Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

```
function intervalRep() {
  if (intervalsRunning === true) {
    rep--;
    document.body.style.background = '#FB2843';
    calcSprintSegments(sprint * 1000);
    longBeep.play();
    intervalTimeouts.push(setTimeout(function() {
        if (rep > 0) {
          document.body.style.background = '#BB39F0';
          lowBeep.play();
          setTimeout(intervalRep, pause * 1000);
        } else {
          intervalsRunning = false;
          intervalTimeouts.forEach(function(t) {
            clearTimeout(t);
          });
          intervalTimeouts = [];
          document.body.style.background = '#4A3DF9';
          cheering.play();
        }
      }, sprint * 1000)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how are you calling the function?. Those second and third calls how and when are they happening?? The function is not self contained since: `rep, pause, sprint, intervalsRunning, intervalsTimeouts` are affecting the behavior and if you call the function more than once then both of the calls are affecting each other (it is a bad design as you can see)

Comment: I understand the design is not the best! Even if all of these remain the same the function behaves differently. Will push and link to Github in a minute

Comment: @RobertoLangarica [link](https://github.com/karinknutsson/work-it/)

Comment: The function is called from countDown(), in modules/intervals.js

Comment: I changed *rep, pause, sprint* to local variables and it seems to have solved the problem. Thank you! Still wondering how I can fix the graphic but this is a whole other issue

Comment: Great to hear that you can solve it.